# checking and removing the duplicate data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have mysql table called it as "R" which contains many fields, but I am worried about only one field that it "email". Email contain email address it will contain duplicate entries. Now I wanna check for duplicate entries and count should increase by 1 for every unique email address and replicated emails should not be counted.

How do I implement this logic.

Kindly help me.
I am a newbie to ruby on rails world!!!

Comment: Is this a table related to the user? Or the actual users. Table? The answer differs depending.

Comment: Its just another table with couple of fields, Email consists of email id's of user. Thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to count the number of unique email addresses for table my_table, and assuming you have set up an ActiveRecord model for it (which would be named MyTable), try:

```
MyTable.count(:email_address, :distinct => true)
```

That will run underlying SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `my_table`.`email_address`) FROM `my_table`
```

That will return a number in both cases.